# MySQL Server stopped (new install on mac osx)

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Hi Stackoverflow world,

please help!  I'm a total noob to programming, and to your community. By trade I'm really in contemporary dance.  I'm trying to boot this up and learn it for a cool performance project.  So I apologize if there is something in the forums that already addresses this issue specifically, but I did research it and didn't get any hits for this issue specifically.

SO - anyway!!  Bashful disclaimers aside, basically, I installed MySQL and tried to get it going, but the server instance is stopped.  What gives?  I even called a programmer friend for help, and he spent over an hour on it with me to no avail.  I know I must have done something wrong, but I honestly have no idea how to solve this.

If you are keen to this kind of thing, and can help me figure it out I'd greatly appreciate it.  My performance project is for a class (and for life, but two for the price of one, haaaaay!) - so I'm kinda in a crunch.

Alas, hopefully you glorious stackoverflow geniuses who i've heard so much about can help me rectify this.

Virtually,
Dancebot

Comment: I am sorry, despite the size of your question, there is very little information to go by. How did you install mysql? How do you know it stopped? Did it install properly? The simplest non-programmers way to install MySql is using a program like http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html, would you  like to try that...

Comment: Consider installing the [community server package](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) provided by MySQL. It works perfectly out of the box. The included configuration panel (added to the System Preferences) makes starting and stopping the server extremely easy.

Comment: Thanks Anne, I don't know what other information to provide.  Basically I downloaded this and installed it from somewhere roughly 8 months ago.  I only re-opened the trouble-shooting task as I need it for a class.

Maybe I should uninstall and reinstall from that link?

Comment: Also, the way i know it stopped is that... it always says "stopped" no matter what I do to start it from the systems preferences pane.

Comment: Hey Guys!!  A good friend of mine saw my yelp for help on facebook and forwarded me to MAMP which is working perfectly, extremely simple install - no fuss, no command line... and we're off and running.  thanks so much for your help... i hope MAMP helps any others out there who ran into trouble.

just out of curiosity though, this morning i noticed the dialog box upon startup that said MYSQL server stopped due to security.  So if anyone wants to take a stab at that, for the principle of the thing, have at it!

Comment: spoken too soon... we are having trouble, but trying to figure it out.  to be continued...